# How to "disable" access to a class in a library?

Tags: c#

Iam writing a library. I have a class called Database and a class called DBManager... Database.cs is doing simple CRUD stuff for a single (defined in the contructor) database. DBManager is handling all the Database instances etc.

I want that users can only call DBManager and never instantiate a Database class for themselves (DBManager should be the only class doing this!)
The layers are: User -> DBManager -> Database

How can i achieve something like this?

Comment: are you exporting a dll at the end?

Comment: i just want to provide a nuget package

Comment: On a side note, if you haven't already checked out this project, it covers some fantastic examples of using DBProviderFactory so that you aren't hard-coding provider specific code:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55890/Don-t-hard-code-your-DataProviders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So currently both `Database` and `DBManager` are `public`. And you want to limit instantiation of `Database` to a controlled way:

> I want that users can only call DBManager and never instantiate a Database class for themselves (DBManager should be the only class doing this!)

The easiest is adjusting accessibility of `Database`'s constructor using the [`internal` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal):

```
public class Database
{
    …

    internal Database(string connectionString)
    {
        …
    }
}
```

That way, only classes in the *same assembly* will be able to call the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Mark it Internal:

```
public AccessibleClass 
{
}

internal NonAccessibleClass 
{
}
```

If you need the Database class to be usable from the outside but not instantiated, then simply change the constructor accessors.

```
public class Database
{
    internal Database() 
    {
       //initialize
    } 
}
```

However it sounds like you're going for the [Factory pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern).